# rich:menuitem passing parameter

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have menu build on Richfaces using rich:menuitem. I need to determine, which menuitem was clicked by user. I tried to use:

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="server" value="#{msg.sidemenu_alldocs_internal_documents_bill_sent_documents}" action="#{billdoc.list}">
            <f:param name="sidemenutype" value="#{bill_sent}"/>
        </rich:menuItem>
```

But, i don't see parameter sidemenutype in my request parameters. Why?

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String docType = (String)context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("sidemenutype");
```

docType is null. Can i somehow pass parameter from jsp to request, using rich:menuitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` (inside your `menuItem`) and setting the docType in a property of your bean, not in the request.

Answer (score 2):

Use `f:setPropertyActionListener` instead.

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{billdoc.bill_sent}" value="#{bill_sent}"/>
```

This expects a property `bill_sent` with a getter and setter in the `billdoc` bean.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage underscore separated properties :)